# Find row in pandas that contain correct set value for a column

Tags: python, pandas

One of my columns in pandas df contains string that represents a set

```
tables,n_estimators,min_samples_split,min_samples_leaf,max_depth
"{'school.csv'}",1024,16,4,8
"{'school.csv', 'univeristy.csv', 'work'}",1024,32,4,16
"{'univeristy.csv'}",1024,4,4,16
```

I am trying to find a row corresponding to a particular set value as follows:

```
hp_row = hp_df.loc[set(eval(hp_df['tables'].to_numpy())) == {school.csv'}]
```

But this clearly does not work.

```
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Any help on how to do it correctly?

Here expected value of hp_row would be

```
"{'school.csv'}",1024,16,4,8
```

Note that I want to compare set objects, not strings.

Thanks

EDIT:
My temp solution (but looking for something more compact and optimized):

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    row = df.iloc[i]
    s = set(eval(row['tables']))
    if s == {"school.csv"}:
        selected_row = row
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you may use `ast.literal_eval` to convert columns `table` from strings to sets and assign it to `s`. Next, use `loc` with `s` to slice

```
import ast

s = df.tables.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df.loc[s == {'school.csv'}]

Out[109]:
           tables  n_estimators  min_samples_split  min_samples_leaf  \
0  {'school.csv'}          1024                 16                 4

   max_depth
0          8
```

Answer (score 0):

in case u want to slice row with set that contains the require element:

```
hp_df[hp_df.apply(lambda row: 'school.csv' in eval(row['tables']),axis=1)]
```